# Consuming a JSON API with PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I am trying to consume a JSON API with PHP.

I have tried using CURL to get a response:

```
curl 'http://104.239.130.176:3000/api/users/authenticate?email=my_username_here&password=my_password'
```

This doesn't give me any response in the terminal.

I have also tried swapping email for username:

```
curl 'http://104.239.130.176:3000/api/users/authenticate?username=my_username_here&password=my_password'
```

I have written the following in a PHP file but this gives me a 404 error in the browser.

```
<?php   
  // Parameters
  $tpm_base_url = 'http://104.239.176.130:3000/'; // ending with /
  $req_uri = 'api/users/authenticate'; // GET /passwords.json
  $username = 'my_username';
  $password = 'my_password';

  // Request headers
  $headers = array( 
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'
  );

  // Request
  $ch = curl_init($tpm_base_url . $req_uri);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); // Includes the header in the output
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password); // HTTP Basic Authentication
  $result = curl_exec($ch); 
  $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
  curl_close($ch);

  // Get headers and body
  list($headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
  $arr_headers = explode("\r\n", $headers);
  $arr_body = json_decode($body, TRUE);

  // Show status and array of passwords
  echo 'Status: ' . $status . '<br/>';
  print_r($arr_body);
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong here. Instructions from the API developer are as follows:

The API has a basic JWT security so first request token.

POST request to: 
http://104.239.176.130:3000/api/users/authenticate

Comment: did you try file_get_contents(url) instead of curl?

Comment: **POST** request to.... as far as I can tell, you're just doing GET requests. And you should use a proper HTTP library instead of trying to roll your own. Gonna save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "username=my_username_here&password=my_password" http://104.239.176.130:3000/api/users/authenticate
```

try this in terminal and see if you have any reponse

In php use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  instead CURLOPT_USERPWD to send the user/pass

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction using the following I was able to receive a token back.


curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"email":"myusername","password":"mypassword"}' http://104.239.120.178:3000/api/users/authenticate

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $ch = curl_init($tpm_base_url . $req_uri);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); // Includes the header in the output
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "email=$username&password=$password");
 $result = curl_exec($ch); 
  $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
  curl_close($ch);
```